# How to efficiently combine bitmaps in Android

Tags: android, image, performance, memory, bitmap

I'm currently trying to create a little helper class that can make one image out of multiple images. It should take the size of the screen and take equal parts of all images and then combine them to one single image that has a little piece of all images side by side.

So far my class successfully creates such an image. The only trouble I have is an enomours amount of used RAM after I created this image. Do you have any suggestions how I can improve the RAM usage after i created that image? (I don't want to run out of memory) Maybe I'm wasting memory the way I create the images (I'm open for better suggestions). 
Important to know is that I can not cache these images on disk since they will never be the same.

What I noticed was that once I run a manual GC RAM usage goes back from around 70MiB to 15MiB.

```
private LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;
private List<Integer> IDs = new ArrayList<>();
private CombinerTask task;

private void combineImages(boolean useScreenSize){
        if(task != null)
            task.cancel(true);
        task = new CombinerTask(useScreenSize);
        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
             task.execute();
        }
    }

class CombinerTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap>{
    private boolean useScreenSize;

    public CombinerTask(boolean useScreenSize){
        this.useScreenSize = useScreenSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void...voids) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay;
        if(useScreenSize){
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ImageCombiner.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);

            for(int x = 0; x < IDs.size(); x++){
                float scaleFactor = (float)size.y / (float)mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(x)).getHeight();
                Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(x)),(int)(mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(x)).getWidth() * scaleFactor), (int)(mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(x)).getHeight() * scaleFactor),false);
                mMemoryCache.put(IDs.get(x),temp);
            }

            bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(size.x,size.y,mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(0)).getConfig());
        }else {
            bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(0)).getWidth(),mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(0)).getHeight(),mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(0)).getConfig());
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);

        for(int i = 0; i < IDs.size(); i++){
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(i)),mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(i)).getWidth()/3,0,bmOverlay.getWidth()/mMemoryCache.size(),mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(i)).getHeight());
            canvas.drawBitmap(bm,bm.getWidth()*i,0,null);
            bm.recycle();
        }
        canvas = null;
        return bmOverlay;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(listener != null)
            listener.combineFinished(bitmap);
        for (int i = 0; i < IDs.size(); i++){
            mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(i)).recycle();
        }
        mMemoryCache = null;
        IDs = null;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this question by myself since I was capable of reducing the amount of needed memory from 70Mib to 2Mib. How I did was pretty simple. Instead of upscaling my image inside my code I only adopt it to the screen aspect ratio. And the scaling will be done by the ImageView itself. This saves nearly 60% of memory.

Also I now recycle most of the bitmaps directly after use and the LruCache will be evicted once all jobs are done.

Here's my updated code (which is not final but a much better starting point than before):

```
private void combineImages(boolean useScreenSize){
    if(task != null)
        task.cancel(true);
    task = new CombinerTask(useScreenSize);
    if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    } else {
         task.execute();
    }
}

class CombinerTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap>{
    private boolean useScreenSize;

    public CombinerTask(boolean useScreenSize){
        this.useScreenSize = useScreenSize;
    }
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void...voids) {
        if(!mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(0)).isRecycled()) {
            Bitmap bmOverlay;
            if (useScreenSize) {
                WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ImageCombiner.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);


                for (int x = 0; x < IDs.size(); x++) {
                    int width = mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(x)).getWidth();
                    int height = mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(x)).getHeight();

                    float scaleFactorWidth = 1f;
                    float scaleFactorHeight = 1f;
                    scaleFactorWidth = (float) size.x / (float) width;
                    scaleFactorHeight = (float) size.y / (float) height;

                    Bitmap temp = null;
                    if (scaleFactorHeight > scaleFactorWidth) {
                        temp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(x)), (int) (width * scaleFactorHeight), (int) (height * scaleFactorHeight), false);
                        Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(temp, 0, 0, size.x, size.y);
                        temp.recycle();
                        temp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(cropped, (int) ((float) cropped.getWidth() / scaleFactorHeight), (int) ((float) cropped.getHeight() / scaleFactorHeight), false);
                        cropped.recycle();

                    } else if (scaleFactorHeight < scaleFactorWidth) {
                        temp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(x)), (int) (width * scaleFactorWidth), (int) (height * scaleFactorWidth), false);
                        Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(temp, 0, 0, size.x, size.y);
                        temp.recycle();
                        temp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(cropped, (int) ((float) cropped.getWidth() / scaleFactorWidth), (int) ((float) cropped.getHeight() / scaleFactorWidth), false);
                        cropped.recycle();
                    }
                    if(mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(x)) != null)
                        mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(x)).recycle();
                    mMemoryCache.put(IDs.get(x), temp);
                }

                bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(0)).getWidth(), mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(0)).getHeight(), mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(0)).getConfig());
            } else {
                bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(0)).getWidth(), mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(0)).getHeight(), mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(0)).getConfig());
            }

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);

            for (int i = 0; i < IDs.size(); i++) {
                Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(i)), 0, 0, bmOverlay.getWidth() / mMemoryCache.size(), mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(i)).getHeight());
                canvas.drawBitmap(bm, bm.getWidth() * i, 0, null);
                bm.recycle();
            }
            canvas = null;
            return bmOverlay;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(listener != null && bitmap != null)
            listener.combineFinished(bitmap);
        for (int i = 0; i < IDs.size(); i++){
            if(mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(i))!= null)
                mMemoryCache.get(IDs.get(i)).recycle();
        }
        mMemoryCache.evictAll();
        IDs.clear();
    }
}
```